# How to submit this function by using onchang checkbox or press button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to submit this function by using onchang checkbox or press button ?

i want to submit form and call function When onchang checkbox or press button,

How can i do that ?

```
<form method="post" id="f1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="one" value="1">1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" name="two" value="2">2<br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#f1').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Add another event listener to listen for the checkboxes `change` event?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Check and uncheck what?

Comment: thank you  isherwood i edit my question success, Check and uncheck it's mean onchange ^^

Comment: @การรกาารนานนานกาพ onChange is an invalid event for checkboxes. It should be only assigned for select lists.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ecx21ttj/) .... look at the console output or network output as you click the `submit` button or any of the `checkboxes`.

You want to let the `submit` button do its job -- **submit the form** for a start. Clicking the `submit` button always triggers the **submit form event**. You want a `checkbox` change event to trigger the same event **submit form event** and the corresponding event handler will take care of the rest.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#f1 :checkbox').on('change',function() {
        $(this.form).submit();
    });
    $('#f1').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my code work , have issue ?

```
<form method="post" id="f1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="one" value="1" onclick="xxx()">1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" name="two" value="2" onclick="xxx()">2<br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="OK" onclick="return xxx();"/>
</form>

    <script>
    function xxx(){
        $('#overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#f1').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#overlay').hide();
                $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: -1 (1) You want by all means to avoid inline JS; its bad practice. Your JS and markup should be separated for easier maintenance. (2) The form you're serializing is not the same form in the markup - **`#advance_search_form_filters`**.

Comment: Yes. What is `$('#xxx')`?

Comment: –  user3558931 --- sorry , i edit success `$('#xxx')` to `$('#f1')`

it's OK ?

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
<form method="post" id="f1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" name="one" value="1" />1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" name="two" value="2" />2<br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#f1').submit(function() {
    $('#overlay').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#f1').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#overlay').hide();
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$('#f1').change(function(){
    $(this).submit();
});
})
</script>
```